Is there a word describing a time interval that would be an antonym to "delay"?
As an example, suppose we have two events -- A, followed by B, happening X minutes apart.
From the perspective of event A, the delay between A and B is X minutes.
From the perspective of event B, the _____ between B and A is X minutes. Is there a single noun that would go in the blank space that would properly convey A happens X minutes before B?
I know Indian-English has the verb prepone, and there's also the verb to precede (by), so you could say "B precedes A by X minutes". I've also looked at the antonym lists on thesaurus.com and Merriam-Webster, but none of the options really feel like they're describing a time interval in the way "delay" does.
"Lead time" is probably the closest compound noun option, but I wonder if there's a single noun one.

I'm pretty sure you could still use delay in the second sentence, albeit at the loss of some clarity. Which is another way of saying the first sentence isn't 100% unambiguous. Far better to say "A is X minutes earlier than B".

It's only an interval of elapsed time, objectively speaking.  delay  is a judgmental term expressing that B should have happened sooner.  Are you asking for a term that means "A should have happened later"?   Your question is not clear enough.

You could just use interval if all you want is a name for a chunk of time between two events, without suggesting that the chunk was too long or too short, or that one of the events was premature or the other was delayed.  If you have a real-world situation (as "lead time" suggests you may) it would be better to pose your question in real terms rather than abstractly. Are we talking about an order date and a delivery date, for example?

OED has five meanings for antecedence, and I'd guess that one is 'the amount of time by which a certain event precedes/preceded a baseline event'. But I can't access OED at this level.

For a crossword, I'd accept that lead time at 8 letters is too long. But in life, lead time is not so long. Just saying.

I believe the technical term is jitter.

You could just say time in both cases

"Delay" is not usually the right word to indicate a time difference. "Delay" implies that something was supposed to happen at one time but actually happened later. You would use "delay" in your case only if A and B were related, usually because one causes the other or they had a common cause or they were expected to happen at the same time. Saying:

There was a ten minute delay between the arrival of the train from Paris and the train from Marseilles.

is poor English, unless they were supposed to arrive at the same time. Saying "difference" or "interval" would be better. Those don't specify which happens first.
The normal and simple way to say this is:

The train from Paris arrives ten minutes before the train from Marseilles.

or

The train from Marseilles arrives ten minutes after the train from Paris.

Simple is almost always good. Try to be simple if at all possible.
"Prepone" is not appropriate because a) it only exists in Indian English (I'll take your word for it that it's considered normal in that dialect - in other dialects it would be considered a mistake) and b) it implies that the time was changed from something else, just like it's more universal antonym "postpone".

Note that delay often conveys not only that the interval is being measured forwards in time, but also that the interval has been introduced, whether intentionally (by design), as in My house alarm has a built-in delay to allow me to enter a code before it goes off) or by misfortunate events that disrupt a previous schedule, as in The storm has caused delays at airports throughout the country. Thus one would not say, *“The delay between breakfast and lunch is four hours.”
There is no single English word that is dual to delay in all of its senses.
